# How to Programmatically set a Product's Multi-Select Attribute by Labels

Tags: product, attributes, programming, multiselect-attribute

If have a multiselect attribute and want to set the selection on a product.

```
$selectedOptions = "red,green,blue";
$product->..... // # what to do?
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Multiselect attributes can be set as a comma separated list (or also an array) containing the attribute value ids.

So first we have to convert the actual values to Magento's internal ids.

```
$attrCode = 'color_base';
$sourceModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
    ->getAttribute($attrCode)->getSource();
$valuesText = explode(',', 'red,green,blue');
$valuesIds = array_map(array($sourceModel, 'getOptionId'), $valuesText);
$product->setData($attrCode, $valuesIds);
$product->save();
```

Comment: this is not working, the page is keep on loading with this code

Answer (score 2):

Modify last line of the above code

```
$product->save();
```

with

```
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, $attrCode);
```

It works

Answer (score 0):

```
$attrCode = 'color_base';
$sourceModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
   ->getAttribute($attrCode)->getSource();
$valuesText = explode(',', 'red,green,blue');
$valuesIds = array_map(array($sourceModel, 'getOptionId'), $valuesText);
$OptionIds = implode(',', $valuesIds); 
$product->setColorBase($attrCode, $OptionIds);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'color_base');
```