# How to set selected value in multiselect attribute

Tags: product, magento-1, event-observer, multiselect-attribute

How to set selected value in multiselect attribute progmatically. I tried this one but it doesn't work for me.

[How to Programmatically set a Product's Multi-Select Attribute by Labels](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3356/how-to-programmatically-set-a-products-multi-select-attribute-by-labels)

the code on the link above doesn't stop from loading

```
$productObj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
$productObj->setData('filter_category','51,52');
$productObj->save();
```

the code above is invoke after `catalog_product_save_after`

Comment: Please post the code of your implementation. Also mention where is it located.

Comment: The code looks OK. I think you should try it on the `_save_before` event.

Comment: @Marius but I need the updated data of the product...

Comment: @marius is right,if  you want this using   catalog_product_save_after then it going infinite   loop

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to do this in the action `catalog_product_save_after` you could simple update the individual product attribute and not the complete product, thus stopping the infinite loop problem.

```
$attrCode = 'your_attribute';
$sourceModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()
    ->getAttribute($attrCode)->getSource();
$valuesText = explode(',', 'red,green,blue');
$valuesIds = array_map(array($sourceModel, 'getOptionId'), $valuesText);
$product->setData($attrCode, $valuesIds);
$product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, $attrCode);
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the problem is that you go into an infinite loop if you save the product again in the `save_after` event.

1. you should use the `save_before` event
2. Don't `load()` the product again, `$product` already contains all data
3. Don't `save()` as the data you set on `$product` will be saved after the event has finished

So the code for your new observer looks like this:

```
public function setFilterCategoryBeforeSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $observer->getProduct()->setData('filter_category','51,52');
}
```

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

You can filter multiple select using finset. Below is a small example of how filter it

```
$collection = $this->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute,array('finset'=>array_search($selection,$valueId)))
            ->setPageSize($limit)
            ->load();
        Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($collection);
```

here $selection is the value of multiple select attribute to be filtered

Comment: I don't understand this... please explain further so that your answer can solve my problem

Comment: from what i understand from your question you need to filter product by labels in multiple select right ??

Comment: no I am not filtering.. I am updating a product

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you are doing ?