# Loop through all products in category, change value and save

Tags: product, category, collection, ce-1.9.0.0

I need to loop through all the products in a particular category, change a custom attribute and then save each product.

Currently i have:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_POST['id']);
$all_products = $_category->getProductCollection();

foreach ($all_products as $product) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());  
    $product->setCustomAttribute(xxxx);
    $product->save();
}
```

Is this best practice and can it be improved for performance? The collections average around 15-20 products in each and i am getting a very slow loadtime or even the script timing out.

I've used `set_time_limit(0);` to try and force it through but i imagine i can improve my code to stop me having to do this? Eventually the collections may have over 100-200 products each so need to find a good performance now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading full product object use it resource model attribute save `(getResource()->saveAttribute).` It is quit quick awsy to save product data.

**Set value:**   `$product->setCustomAttribute('yourval');`

**Save it value using resource attribute**

```
 $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'custom_attributte');
```

**it only save this attribute not all attribute**

**Full code:**

```
foreach ($all_products as $product) {
    $product->setCustomAttribute(xxxx);
    $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product, 'custom_attributte');
}
```

if your value in array then  implode()
 $product->setCustomAttribute(implode(',',array()));

Comment: Thanks Amit. The custom attribute value is a multi select (so comes in as an array) - does this make a difference? Just tried and nothing was updating

Comment: array should take option id and it format like array(4,8,9)

Comment: see at http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3356/how-to-programmatically-set-a-products-multi-select-attribute-by-labels

Comment: Is there a way to not use the save() for 'categoryIds' when setting them for the products?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you shouldnt be accessing the `$_POST` super global variable directly. You should use the Magento request object for that.

Also, you shouldn't need to `load` the product, you already have the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` object from the collection.

Not unnecessarily re-loading the product should speed up your code quite easily.

For super performance and kind-of-correct handling of `$_POST` (I dont know where this code is being executed, so I'm grabbing the request object direct) you can do something like the following.

```
//If you're in a controller you should be able to call $this->getRequest()
$categoryId= Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('id');
$storeCode = 'default';

$storeId = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeCode)->getId();

$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

if ($storeId && $_category->getId()) {
    $all_products = $_category->getProductCollection();

    $all_products->getSelect()->reset(Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)->columns('entity_id');

    $all_products->setPageSize(500);

    for ($curPage = 1; $curPage <= $all_products->getLastPageNumber(); $curPage++) {
        $all_products->clear();
        $all_products->setCurPage($curPage);

        $ids = array();
        foreach ($all_products as $product) {
            $ids[] = $product->getId();
        }

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
                $ids,
                array('custom_attribute' => 'xxxx'),
                $storeId
            );
        }
    }
}
```